# Move every x(dynamic) number of lines to a single line [Shell]

Tags: linux, excel, shell, awk

So I have data that looks like this

```
/blah
    etc1: etc
    etc2
    etc3: etc
    etc4
/blah
    etc1: etc
    etc2
    etc3
/blah
    etc1: etc
    etc2
    etc3: etc
    etc4
/blah
    etc1
    etc2
```

So I can't do a specific number of lines, so thought was to use / as a delimiter and put every line after until / on same line(comma delimited?)
Ideal Expected Output:

```
/blah,etc1: etc,etc2,etc3: etc,etc4,,
/blah,etc1,etc2,etc3,,
/blah,etc1: etc,etc2,etc3: etc,etc4,,
/blah,etc1,etc2,,
```

Prefer shell/bash/ksh but an excel solution would work too.

Comment: So what have you tried so far to achieve your result and what errors (if any) did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an `awk` solution:

```
awk ' 
  /^\// { if (NR > 1) print ","; printf "%s,", $0; next } 
  { gsub(/^ +| +$/, ""); printf "%s,", $0 } 
  END { print "," }
' file
```

Note that it assumes that the input file starts with a `/blah`-like line, but doesn't end with one.

Crammed into a (less readable) one-liner:

```
awk '/^\// {if(NR>1) print","; printf"%s,",$0; next} {gsub(/^ +| +$/, ""); printf"%s,",$0} END {print","}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` solution

```
sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\s+/,/g' input | sed 's/$/,,/'
```

you get,

```
/blah,etc1: etc,etc2,etc3: etc,etc4,,
/blah,etc1: etc,etc2,etc3,,
/blah,etc1: etc,etc2,etc3: etc,etc4,,
/blah,etc1,etc2,,
```